# Best way to keep development and testing in synch

Tags: testing, development-process, teamwork, team, automation

We have 1 frontend developer and 2 backend developers and 1 QA. QA is responsible for writing the end-to-end tests using Cypress. FE developer writes the unit tests. Backend developers write the unit tests in the backend repo while QA writes the microservice integration and e2e tests.

I'd like for QA and developers to be able to work in sync such that when the pull request is created by the developer, it gets reviewed but should be merged only when the integration and e2e tests are ready by the QA that should be worked on in the same feature branch.

Is this the right approach? What's the best way to keep the development and testing in sync?

We also have a CI/CD pipeline so when the code gets merged it is important that is has all the tests in place

Developers do not seem to like this approach much as they need their code merged into the develop branch at the earliest so their next feature branch that gets created from develop has the recent changes.

Answer (score 2):

#### Incentives

Are they in the right place for what you want?

From what I'm hearing the developers have a vested interest to merge code as quickly as possible, potentially even fast to the detriment of other needs. As you've pointed out they are rewarded for getting their feature branch into the next build.

The QA on the other hand has a vested interest in ensuring good test coverage, even if that means a feature branch does not make the next build.

That's a conflict of interest.

That is not necessarily a bad thing. Adversarial testing is a good way to uncover bugs. But on a collaborative project, conflict always means going slower.

#### Values

So what is it that you value? When it comes down to it what is it you will pick and forgo the others?

In this situation is it:

1. We want features, the people can beta-test for us!
2. We want well tested code! Features?! what are those foreign things? Never heard of them!

If the value is to get the features to the people, then the devs incentives are right. The QA is, and always will be playing catch up.

If the value is to ensure only tested code gets through, then the incentives need to change. It must be made apparent to the devs that it isn't enough to have written the feature and their own unit tests. The feature isn't going anywhere till QA have written their own tests, and that they pass.

Now though you will have an issue in the team balance. 3 Devs vs 1 QA is unbalanced. You could rectify this by hiring more QAs, but the other solution is to get the developers assisting in the QA work for the other side, with the QA providing a 4 eye check on the testing they do.

ie. The front end developer can test the backend system, and the backend devs can test the front end.

By doing this the devs gain an appreciation of testing, and the learning they do will feed back into the way they develop the system, making it easier to test in future. It will also improve test coverage, and because developers love to optimise probably improve test stability and execution speed. It also draws the devs into thinking of the QA as on their side, which should lesson resentment when their branch doesn't make the next build.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was under the impression that in agile teams it was usually 1 QA for 3-4 developers so thought we were doing okay in that area. We are developing an application from scratch so building features and building fast is important but there is a lot of stress on well-test code that it is hard to let go of the much-needed sync between the developers and the testers. The developers want the code merged just so that they will have an "updated" copy of the codebase when they start working on the new feature. The QA however easily falls behind.

Comment: We also have a CI/CD pipeline so when the code gets merged it is important that is has all the tests in place

Comment: The ratio depends on the work and how hard it is to test, there isn't a magic number. IF QA is falling behind, and test coverage is valuable then they need extra support either more QA, or get the devs to support them. On the development front it looks like you can reduce tension by figuring out how to give devs an updated database, without placing the feature into production. One way to do this is with feature toggles. Just remember that the toggle has to be removed lest you make a KnightCapital move.

Comment: @Kain0_0: you are perfectly right with the former comment ("The ratio depends on the work "), still your answer says  "3 Devs vs 1 QA is unbalanced" - looks contradictory to me.

Comment: @DocBrown Fair enough, in the environment I work in the ratio is closer to 1 to 1. I implied there was an imbalance based on the values at play though. If they are happy with the status quo, then its okay. But the status quo is obviously undesired (hence the question) which lead me to believe there was an imbalance. I wasn't aware of the chief complaint from the devs (lack of up to date db) that was causing them to rush the QA, which could be addressed by a process change, and then see if there is still an perceived imbalance.